# C code segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault, coredump

I have tried commenting out code and checking where it is giving me a segmentation fault, but could not find it. I cannot even install the gcc debugger to check. Please help!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

FILE *file;
char *registers[] = {"r0", "r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7"};
char *regInBinary[] = {"000", "001", "010", "011", "100", "101", "110", "111"};
char delimiters[4] = " ,\n";
char binaryInstruction[17];

void convertToBinary(char *line);
void binaryToHex();

// Converting each line of source file into 16 bit binary
void convertToBinary(char *line){
    int count = 0;

    char *token = strtok(line, delimiters);
    while(token != NULL){
        // Opcodes
        if(strcmp(token, "add") == 0)
            strcpy(binaryInstruction, "0001");
        if(strcmp(token, "and") == 0)
            strcpy(binaryInstruction, "0101");
      //  if(strcmp(token, "halt") == 0)
      //      main();


        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){ // appends registers in binary
            if(strcmp(token, registers[i]) == 0){
                strcat(binaryInstruction, regInBinary[i]);
                count++;

                if(count == 2){
                    strcat(binaryInstruction, "000");
                }
             }
        }

        token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

}

// Converting 16 bit binary into hex
void binaryToHex(){
    char hex[5];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 0){
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            hex[j] = binaryInstruction[i];
            i++;
        }
        printf("%x", (int)strtol(hex, NULL, 2));
    }
    printf("\n");
}


// Starting program Part1
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[40];

    if(argc != 2)
        printf("Usage: %s source_file\n", argv[0]);
    else
        file = fopen(argv[1], "t1.asm"); // open source file

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)){
        convertToBinary(line);
        binaryToHex();
    }
    //printf("f025")
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

so this code compiles perfectly on my mac terminal with gcc but throws a segmentation fault when i feed a t1.asm file.

This is a C program to translate LC3�s AND, ADD and HALT assembly language instructions into machine code.

Thanks!

Comment: First stop is your debugger and stepping through your code to find the fault. If you can't install the debugger (?) you're flying blind. Install your debugger. Figure out how or you'll be at a huge disadvantage here. Remember: "It compiles" is often a long, long way away from "it does what I want".

Comment: There's a concerningly large number of *magic numbers* in here, that is numbers with no explanation for their origin. You're also leaning quite heavily on global variables which is an unsustainable practice. Move those local to the functions that need them, pass them through if they're required elsewhere.

Comment: Money's on `char binaryInstruction[17];` being way too tiny for what you're jamming into it and your program explodes.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 0){` .. technically not a problem since you increment `i` in the body of the loop, but this is weird. Change it to a `while` loop or change the afterthought/incrementation part to `i=i+4`.

Comment: error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  for example: this: `printf("Usage: %s source_file\n", argv[0]);
` should be: `fprintf( stderr, "Usage: %s source_file\n", argv[0]);`

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding these two lines: `int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)`  data should be kept with the users of that data.  I.E. limit the scope of the data.  Suggest:  `for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++)`

Comment: in the `main()` function: when the number of command line parameters is not correct, after outputting the error message should call `exit()`, NOT continue to execute the program.   Similar considerations exist for when checking the results of calling `fopen()`, etc.

Comment: when writing a prototype for a function that takes no parameters, place `void` between the parens.  Otherwise the compiler will generate code to accept any number, any kind of parameters.  Not what you really want.

Comment: in the function: `binaryToHex()`, the local array: `hex[5];` is only having the first 4 bytes set,  I.E. the fifth byte contains garbage (what ever trash was on the stack at that location.  The function: `strtol()` expects a pointer to a NUL terminated string.  Strongly suggest declaring the `hex[]` array as: `char hex[5] = {'\0'};`

Comment: regarding: `file = fopen(argv[1], "t1.asm");`  1) the second parameter is the 'mode', not some file name. 2) check (!=NULL) the returned value.  suggest: `FILE *file = fopen( argv[1], "r" );  if( NULL == file ) { perror( "fopen failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: regarding: `//  if(strcmp(token, "halt") == 0)
      //      main();`   NEVER call `main()` recursively,  Infact, never call `main()` from within your code

Comment: As an aside:  there are (usually) a couple of hundred different instructions AND the actual object code can differ, depending on the operands AND many instructions are a single byte AND some instructions are several bytes.  So the function: `convertToBinary()` needs a lot of work

Comment: regarding: `for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 0)`  this is not correct as the index variable `i` is not being changed.  Also, the scope of data should be limited as much as possible.  given the posted code, suggest: remove the statement: `int i, j;`  and replace: `for(i = 0; i < 16; i = i + 0) { for(j = 0; j < 4; j++)` with: `for( int i = 0; i < 16; i += 4 ) { for( int j=0; j < 4; j++ )`

Answer (score 0):

`file = fopen(arv[1], "t1.asm");`

should be

`file = fopen(argv[1], "r");`